# How convert "2020-10-05T06:15:00Z" string to date in R?

Tags: r

I tried the following code, however got NAs
 `as.Date(gsub("T|Z"," ", "2020-10-05T06:15:00Z"), format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ")`
What should I change?

Comment: Try this `as.POSIXct("2020-10-05T06:15:00Z", format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')`

Comment: Also `as.POSIXlt(trimws(gsub("T|Z"," ", "2020-10-05T06:15:00Z")), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz = 'GMT')`